# Text processing Aptly output file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a text file made from the output of the repository management tool `aptly`, which lists my published repositories, from which I need to extract information.

The file format is as follows:

```
Published repositories:
 * test_repo_one/xenial [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [xenial-main_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-main]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}, {multiverse: [xenial-multiverse_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-multiverse]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}, {restricted: [xenial-restricted_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-restricted]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}, {universe: [xenial-universe_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-universe]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}
 * test_repo_one/xenial-security [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [xenial-security-main_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-main]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}, {multiverse: [xenial-security-multiverse_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-multiverse]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}, {restricted: [xenial-security-restricted_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-restricted]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}, {universe: [xenial-security-universe_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-universe]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}
 * test_repo_two/trusty [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [trusty-main_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-main]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}, {multiverse: [trusty-multiverse_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-multiverse]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}, {restricted: [trusty-restricted_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-restricted]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}, {universe: [trusty-universe_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-universe]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}
...
```

The last line of the output ends in a new line.

The "Published repositories:" line is not required.

For each of the lines starting '  *' I need to remove extraneous information, leaving only snapshot names. There is no way to do this in `aptly`. The desired output for the first of these lines is.

```
test_repo_one/xenial [xenial-main_20190311] [xenial-multiverse_20190311] [xenial-restricted_20190311] [xenial-universe_20190311]
```

The square brackets are not essential either so a solution that retains or removes these is fine. I'd prefer a `sed` or `awk` solution but anything that works would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It *looks* like `aptly` has a quite rich `-format` templating feature: [PACKAGE DISPLAY FORMAT](https://www.aptly.info/doc/feature/package-display/) - are you not able to get closer to your desired output with that? It will likely be more robust than any kind of regex-based post processing.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but unfortunately the templating feature is only applied to the search commands, which return lists of the packages in a mirror/repo/snapshot. As i'm looking for the snapshots that make up a published repo it's not possible to use for my purposes.

Comment: What command do you use to produce this list ? ( Yes, I know it's `aptly`, but what's the full command and flags ?)

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy it was `aptly publish list` no options. It's aptly 0.9.6 which is in the xenial repos, so unfortunately no `aptly publish show` command available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Perl approach:

```
$ perl -lne 'next unless /^\s*\*\s*(\S+)/; $n=$1; @k=(/\{.+?:\s*\[(.+?)\]/g); print "$n @k"' file 
test_repo_one/xenial xenial-main_20190311 xenial-multiverse_20190311 xenial-restricted_20190311 xenial-universe_20190311
test_repo_one/xenial-security xenial-security-main_20190311 xenial-security-multiverse_20190311 xenial-security-restricted_20190311 xenial-security-universe_20190311
test_repo_two/trusty trusty-main_20190312 trusty-multiverse_20190312 trusty-restricted_20190312 trusty-universe_20190312
```

#### Explanation

- `perl -lne`: read the input file line by line (`-n`), remove trailing newlines (`-l`) and run the script given by `-e` on each line. The `-l` also adds a newline to each `print` call.
- `next unless /^\s*\*\s*(\S+)/;` : find the name of the repo, so the first stretch of non-whitespace characters (`\S+`) on a line that starts with 0 or more whitespace characters (`^\s*`), then a `*` (`\*`), and 0 or more whitespace characters again. The longest stretch of non-whitespace after that is what we want. If this line doesn't match this regex, the `next` will move us onto the next line.
- `$n=$1` : save what was captured by the match above (the `(\S+)` in parentheses, `$1`) as `$n`.
- `@k=(/\{.+?:\s*\[(.+?)\]/g)`: find all cases where we have a `{`, any other characters and then a `:`, followed by whitespace and a `[` and capture anything between the `[` and the `]`. Save all matching strings in the array `@k`.
- `print "$n @k"` : finally, print the name of the repo, the `$n`, and the array `@k` from above.

---

If you prefer to have the square brackets included, you can use:

```
$ perl -lne 'next unless /^\s*\*\s*(\S+)/; $n=$1; @k=(/\{.+?:\s*(\[.+?\])/g); print "$n @k"' file 
test_repo_one/xenial [xenial-main_20190311] [xenial-multiverse_20190311] [xenial-restricted_20190311] [xenial-universe_20190311]
test_repo_one/xenial-security [xenial-security-main_20190311] [xenial-security-multiverse_20190311] [xenial-security-restricted_20190311] [xenial-security-universe_20190311]
test_repo_two/trusty [trusty-main_20190312] [trusty-multiverse_20190312] [trusty-restricted_20190312] [trusty-universe_20190312]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Two answers in one

I've posted two answers here:

- A bash script which is hopefully easier to understand
- A one-liner using common Linux utilities `grep`, `sed` and `cut`

## How the Bash script looks in operation

I've turned off gnome-terminal line wrap to make input and output files easier to read.

```bash
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/askubuntu$ tput rmam # Turn off line wrap
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/askubuntu$ cat aptfilein
Published repositories:
 * test_repo_one/xenial [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [xenial-main_20190311]: Snapshot from mirr}
 * test_repo_one/xenial-security [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [xenial-security-main_20190311]: }
 * test_repo_two/trusty [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [trusty-main_20190312]: Snapshot from mirr}
...
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/askubuntu$ time aptfileparse.sh
5 lines read from aptfilein
3 lines written to aptfileout

real    0m0.025s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.004s
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/askubuntu$ cat aptfileout
 test_repo_one/xenial [xenial-main_20190311] [xenial-multiverse_20190311] [xenial-restricted_201]
 test_repo_one/xenial-security [xenial-security-main_20190311] [xenial-security-multiverse_20190]
 test_repo_two/trusty [trusty-main_20190312] [trusty-multiverse_20190312] [trusty-restricted_201]
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/askubuntu$
```

---

## The actual Bash script

Remember to make the script executable with `chmod a+x script.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: aptfileparse.sh
# PATH: ~/askubuntu
# DESC: Parse Apt File giving new lines.
# DATE: July 1, 2019.
# NOTE: For: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127821/text-processing-aptly-output-file
#       Program would be ~10 lines shorter (but harder to read) with arrays.

: <<'END'
/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

INPUT FILE LAYOUT
=================

Published repositories:
 * test_repo_one/xenial [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [xenial-main_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-main]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}, {multiverse: [xenial-multiverse_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-multiverse]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}, {restricted: [xenial-restricted_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-restricted]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}, {universe: [xenial-universe_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-universe]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}
 * test_repo_one/xenial-security [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [xenial-security-main_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-main]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}, {multiverse: [xenial-security-multiverse_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-multiverse]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}, {restricted: [xenial-security-restricted_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-restricted]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}, {universe: [xenial-security-universe_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-universe]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}
 * test_repo_two/trusty [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [trusty-main_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-main]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}, {multiverse: [trusty-multiverse_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-multiverse]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}, {restricted: [trusty-restricted_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-restricted]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}, {universe: [trusty-universe_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-universe]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}
...

OUTPUT FILE LAYOUT
==================

 test_repo_one/xenial [xenial-main_20190311] [xenial-multiverse_20190311] [xenial-restricted_20190311] [xenial-universe_20190311]

Five fields to extract: name, main, multiverse, restricted, universe

----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
END

 INPUT="aptfilein"
OUTPUT="aptfileout"

> "$OUTPUT" # Erase previous output file

# Read all input lines
while IFS= read -r line ; do

    let CountIn++
    ! [[ "$line" =~ " *" ]] && continue     # skip lines not starting " *"
    # Get name
    line="${line#" * "}"                    # remove leading " * "
    lout="${line%%" "*}"                    # name is up to next " "
    line="${line#" "*}"                     # remove name from line
    # Get main
    line="${line#*"{main: "}"               # remove leading "{main: "
    lout="$lout ${line%%":"*}"              # main is up to next ":"
    line="${line#":"*}"                     # remove name from line
    # Get multiverse
    line="${line#*"{multiverse: "}"         # remove leading "{multiverse: "
    lout="$lout ${line%%":"*}"              # maultiverse is up to next ":"
    line="${line#":"*}"                     # remove multiverse from line
    # Get restricted
    line="${line#*"{restricted: "}"         # remove leading "{restricted: "
    lout="$lout ${line%%":"*}"              # restricted is up to next ":"
    line="${line#":"*}"                     # remove restricted from line
    # Get universe
    line="${line#*"{universe: "}"           # remove leading "{universe: "
    lout="$lout ${line%%":"*}"              # universe is up to next ":"
    line="${line#":"*}"                     # remove universe from line

    # Append line to output file with leading space
    echo " $lout" >> "$OUTPUT"
    let CountOut++

done < "$INPUT"

echo  "$CountIn lines read from $INPUT"
echo "$CountOut lines written to $OUTPUT"
```

---

## One-liner with common utilities

One-liners are popular in the Linux community and there are some excellent `awk` and `perl` answers posted in this Q&A. Here is an example using common utilities most experienced command line users are familiar with:

```bash
$ time grep ^" \*" aptfilein | sed 's/ \* //;s/ /: /;s/^/ /' | cut -d':' -f1,3,6,9,12 --output-delimiter=''
 test_repo_one/xenial [xenial-main_20190311] [xenial-multiverse_20190311] [xenial-restricted_20190311] [xenial-universe_20190311]
 test_repo_one/xenial-security [xenial-security-main_20190311] [xenial-security-multiverse_20190311] [xenial-security-restricted_20190311] [xenial-security-universe_20190311]
 test_repo_two/trusty [trusty-main_20190312] [trusty-multiverse_20190312] [trusty-restricted_20190312] [trusty-universe_20190312]

real    0m0.011s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.008s
```

- `grep ^" \*" aptfilein` - the `grep` command selects lines containing a search string. The carrot (`^`) denotes the string must start at the beginning of the line. The backslash (`\`) denotes the asterisk/splat (`*`) is to be taken literally and not act as a wildcard character that selects everything. In summary this `grep` command selects all lines beginning with  `*` in file `aptfilein`.
- `sed` is a "stream editor" that edits lines coming in and changes them and passes them out. There are three `sed` changes here `'s/ \* //;s/ /: /;s/^/ /'`. The changes are between quotes (`'`) and delineated (separated) by a semi-colon (`;`) deliminator. They are broken down in next three points.
- `s/ \* //` - search first occurrence of `*` and change it to null. This will erase the `*` that begins at each line.
- `s/ /: /` - searches for the first space and changes it into a colon (`:`) followed by a space. This is necessary to change our first field into a key. For example `test_repo_one/xenial`  becomes `test_repo_one/xenial:` .
- `s/^/ /` - tells `sed` to insert a space at the beginning of each line.
- `cut -d':' -f1,3,6,9,12 --output-delimiter=''` - Uses the `cut` command to select key fields # 1, 3, 6, 9 and 12. The key fields are delimited by a colon as argument `-d':'` stipulates. Normally output fields are delimited the same but this is overridden to null using --output-delimiter=''` parameter.

**Note:** The one-liner is faster than bash which is slower at string processing.

Comment: Thanks for the different approaches and helpful explanations. I decided to go with terdon's answer as it avoids the need to hardcode the field numbers, but it was a tough choice. You've already had my +1.

Answer (score 2):

My awk approach:

```
$ cat 1.txt 
Published repositories:
 * test_repo_one/xenial [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [xenial-main_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-main]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}, {multiverse: [xenial-multiverse_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-multiverse]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}, {restricted: [xenial-restricted_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-restricted]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}, {universe: [xenial-universe_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-universe]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial [src]}
 * test_repo_one/xenial-security [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [xenial-security-main_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-main]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}, {multiverse: [xenial-security-multiverse_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-multiverse]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}, {restricted: [xenial-security-restricted_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-restricted]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}, {universe: [xenial-security-universe_20190311]: Snapshot from mirror [xenial-security-universe]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security[src]}
 * test_repo_two/trusty [i386,amd64] publishes {main: [trusty-main_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-main]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}, {multiverse: [trusty-multiverse_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-multiverse]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}, {restricted: [trusty-restricted_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-restricted]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}, {universe: [trusty-universe_20190312]: Snapshot from mirror [trusty-universe]: http//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty[src]}

$ awk '$1=="*"{split ($0, a, /:/); print $2 a[2] a[5] a[8] a[11]}' 1.txt 
test_repo_one/xenial [xenial-main_20190311] [xenial-multiverse_20190311] [xenial-restricted_20190311] [xenial-universe_20190311]
test_repo_one/xenial-security [xenial-security-main_20190311] [xenial-security-multiverse_20190311] [xenial-security-restricted_20190311] [xenial-security-universe_20190311]
test_repo_two/trusty [trusty-main_20190312] [trusty-multiverse_20190312] [trusty-restricted_20190312] [trusty-universe_20190312]
```